# List of new and changed from package files

Tags: centos, backup, yum, rpm

I want to list all files that differ from the rpm provided files on my system, so I could backup them and have complete backup with all configurations. I've found `rpm -qa` and `yum verify` commands (I don't know the difference, but whatever), but those commands do not detect new files. I can iterate over every file in the system and check it with `rpm -q -f filename`, but it looks very long. Is there better approach? I think that `cruft` and `cruft-ng` tools do that for Debian-based distributions, so probably I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Backup all of /etc/, and any config you know is elsewhere. Optionally, if you don't have a good installed package list, your rpm database in /var/lib/rpm/. Consider incremental backups of these directories, although fulls don't take up that much space.

To find what rpm thinks are config files, run `rpm -qac`. There is some non /etc/ strangeness in here that are probably mislabeled, but review it anyway.

`rpm -Va` attempts to ignore config files. Those are supposed to be different, from a package integrity perspective.

---

Obviously, restore test this. Have fun destroying a test host. Then recover it with a new install, restored configs, and restored data.

Comment: I have never known `rpm -Va` to ignore configuration files. Are you certain this is the case?

Comment: That is what I observe at least.  Try it: `rpm -Va | grep /etc/fstab`  Not that it particularly matters, a backup of all of  /etc/  plus whatever else you need might be simpler.

Comment: That is interesting! I do see plenty of other config files under etc, but not that one. I dug deeper and found this Red Hat KB article. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/31645